# PLUCK one row WHERE postgres column name includes underscore

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am trying to get a row/rows in a POSTGRES table where a column name with an underscore ("Cas_NO") matches a specific string. I am having trouble formulating a working query:

```
@array_a = ["a", "b", "c"]
@array_b
@array_a.each do |a|
    @array_b << Database.where("\"BAS_No\" = ?", a).pluck(:INBC_name)
end
```

Running the above code gives me the entire rows from the Database table, not just where "BAS_No" matches "a" or "b" or "c" in the @array_a

Answer (score 0):

That's not your real code. Saying this:

```
Database.where("\"BAS_No\" = ?", %w[a b c])
```

will produce an SQL WHERE clause like this:

```
where ("BAS_No" = 'a','b','c')
```

and that's not valid SQL so you should get an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` exception rather than a bunch of data.

In any case, you shouldn't use `=` with a list of values, you want to use `IN` and the easiest way to get that is to let ActiveRecord build the SQL:

```
Database.where(:BAS_No => a).pluck(:INBC_Name)
#--------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or, if you're allergic to hashrockets:

```
Database.where(BAS_No: a).pluck(:INBC_Name)
#--------------^^^^^^^^^
```

When `a` is an array, those will produce `IN (...)` expressions in the WHERE clause and you should get back what you're expecting.